# Help me with this Error in Array while Printing?

Tags: java, arrays

It's say's type mismatch.... even if an appropriate type is selected....

I am attaching the code for better understanding....

```
    public  void calucate()
    {
        int Sum=0;
        arraySumOfRows= new int[20];
        for(int i=0;i<Array1.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<Array1.length;j++)
            {
                Sum=Sum+Array1[i][j];
                arraySumOfRows[i]=Sum;
            }

        }

        for(int i=0;i<arraySumOfRows.length;i++)
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arraySumOfRows[i]));


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. `arraySumOfRows[i]` is an integer and `Arrays.toString()` expects an array. Just use:

   ```
   System.out.println(arraySumOfRows[i]);
   ```
2. Your inner loop is wrong. I should be:

   ```
   for(int j=0;j<Array1[i].length;j++)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

notice i moves the line `arraySumOfRows[i]=Sum` out of the internal (j)loop, i think it belongs to the external one (i)Loop.

```
public void calucate()
    {
        int Sum=0;
        arraySumOfRows= new int[20];
        for(int i=0;i<Array1.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<Array1.length;j++)
            {
                Sum=Sum+Array1[i][j];                    
            }
            arraySumOfRows[i]=Sum;    
        }

        for(int i=0;i<arraySumOfRows.length;i++)
            System.out.println(Integer.toString(arraySumOfRows[i]));    

    }
```

Comment: Their is no `ToString` field (or method) on integer.

Comment: @Peter: There is Integer.ToString but not int.ToString